# opengl matrix math multiplication

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, 3d

I am writing a simple c 4x4 matrix math library and wanted some feedback, especially from people with opengl experience.

Typically there's two ways to do matrix multiplication. I tested this code and it works, according to results from wolfram alpha but my main concern is that this matrix is in the right order.

My matrix is just an array of 16 doubles.

The code to do the multiplication is below

```
out->m[0]  = ( a->m[0]  *  b->m[0]) + (a->m[1]  * b->m[4]) + (a->m[2]  *  b->m[8]) + (a->m[3]  * b->m[12] );
out->m[4]  = ( a->m[4]  *  b->m[0]) + (a->m[5]  * b->m[4]) + (a->m[6]  *  b->m[8]) + (a->m[7]  * b->m[12] );
out->m[8]  = ( a->m[8]  *  b->m[0]) + (a->m[9]  * b->m[4]) + (a->m[10] *  b->m[8]) + (a->m[11] * b->m[12] );
out->m[12] = ( a->m[12] *  b->m[0]) + (a->m[13] * b->m[4]) + (a->m[14] *  b->m[8]) + (a->m[15] * b->m[12] );

out->m[1]  = ( a->m[0]  *  b->m[1]) + (a->m[1]  * b->m[5]) + (a->m[2]  * b->m[9])  + (a->m[3]  * b->m[13] );
out->m[5]  = ( a->m[4]  *  b->m[1]) + (a->m[5]  * b->m[5]) + (a->m[6]  * b->m[9])  + (a->m[7]  * b->m[13] );
out->m[9]  = ( a->m[8]  *  b->m[1]) + (a->m[9]  * b->m[5]) + (a->m[10] * b->m[9])  + (a->m[11] * b->m[13] );
out->m[13] = ( a->m[12] *  b->m[1]) + (a->m[13] * b->m[5]) + (a->m[14] * b->m[9])  + (a->m[15] * b->m[13] );

out->m[2]  = ( a->m[0]  *  b->m[2]) + (a->m[1]  * b->m[6]) + (a->m[2]  * b->m[10]) + (a->m[3]  * b->m[14] );
out->m[6]  = ( a->m[4]  *  b->m[2]) + (a->m[5]  * b->m[6]) + (a->m[6]  * b->m[10]) + (a->m[7]  * b->m[14] );
out->m[10] = ( a->m[8]  *  b->m[2]) + (a->m[9]  * b->m[6]) + (a->m[10] * b->m[10]) + (a->m[11] * b->m[14] );
out->m[14] = ( a->m[12] *  b->m[2]) + (a->m[13] * b->m[6]) + (a->m[14] * b->m[10]) + (a->m[15] * b->m[14] );

out->m[3]  = ( a->m[0]  *  b->m[3]) + (a->m[1]  * b->m[7]) + (a->m[2]  * b->m[11]) + (a->m[3]  * b->m[15] );
out->m[7]  = ( a->m[4]  *  b->m[3]) + (a->m[5]  * b->m[7]) + (a->m[6]  * b->m[11]) + (a->m[7]  * b->m[15] );
out->m[11] = ( a->m[8]  *  b->m[3]) + (a->m[9]  * b->m[7]) + (a->m[10] * b->m[11]) + (a->m[11] * b->m[15] );
out->m[15] = ( a->m[12] *  b->m[3]) + (a->m[13] * b->m[7]) + (a->m[14] * b->m[11]) + (a->m[15] * b->m[15] );
```

I wanted to make sure that this will give me the correct results for setting up my transformation matrix.

matrix m = 1,3,4,-1,5,6,7,-1,8,8,8,-1,0,0,0,1
which is arranged in memory like this:

```
1,3,4,-1
5,6,7,-1
8,8,8,-1
0,0,0,1
```

which I think is the way opengl lays out it's matrix as 16 numbers.

using my code my answer comes out to be

```
[   48.000000   53.000000   57.000000   -9.000000   ]
[   91.000000   107.000000  118.000000  -19.000000  ]
[   112.000000  136.000000  152.000000  -25.000000  ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    ]
```

which is the transpose of wolfram alpha's answer.

```
(48 | 91  | 112 | 0
 53 | 107 | 136 | 0
 57 | 118 | 152 | 0
 -9 | -19 | -25 | 1)
```

Typically it looks like this, vertex point **v** model, view, projection matrices

```
position = projection * view * model * v
```

Comment: You know, loops are a thing and any modern, decent compiler will actually be able to unroll it and often also detect that this is vectorizable. And even if the compiler doesn't catch it, modern CPUs have become frightingly efficient internally vectorizing that code.

Comment: @datenwolf How do CPUs vectorize code if the compiler did not generate instructions for it?

Comment: I'd like this to stay focused on the man, please keep the discussion around that topic. I'd like to avoid it becoming a discussion about what a cpu or compiler can or cannot do for you.

Comment: Please clarify your layout. Memory is 1D, so you cannot have a 2D memory layout. On the other hand, a matrix is 2D, so your matrix representation (m = 1, 3, 4 ...) does not make sense. Also how are these results to be interpreted?

Comment: I guess, you might have mis-interpreted Wolfram Alpha's output. If you have calculated the square of the above matrix, this is the transposed result (correct result has 53 in the first row, second column).

Comment: @meaning-matters: Google "Haswell Sandy-Bridge microarchitecture trace  optimization". The essence is, that in easily predictable code (and the loops of matrix multiplication are highly predictive) modern CPUs will quickly collect enough statistics to "understand" what's going on and optimize their actual operations. These days so called "machine code" is in fact just another round of intermediary that gets JIT-ed into the actual on-the-metal instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say you why your results differ but one help is, if you send the matrix into a GLSL uniform dMat4, you can use the build in transpose functionallity of OpenGL to get the right matrix alignment:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv( Uniform_Location, 1, GL_TRUE, MatrixPointer );
```

The third parameter means, if OpenGL should transpose the matrix before setting the uniform.

Comment: this might be the best comment yet, if no one has a better solution this might be the answer. One reason why the results differ is typically matrix multiplication is row major in programming but opengl requires column major. This is my first time writing such a library and so there are quite a few places where things can go left. At least with this option I know there's a way to do a quick transpose at least while debugging.